# Golang mobile package installation issue

Tags: go

I am trying to install go package for mobile using,

```
desktop:~$ go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
```

But it gives this error

> package golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile: unrecognized import path
>   "golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile" (https fetch: Get
>   https://golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile?go-get=1: http: error
>   connecting to proxy http://192.168.0.136:8080/: dial tcp
>   192.168.0.136:8080: getsockopt: connection refused)

Comment: Are you somehow connected trough a proxy server?

Comment: i don't think so ,is there any way to check it?

Comment: Check if git is configured to use a proxy. `git config --get http.proxy`. And when writing SO questions, you should not use quote syntax if you are not quoting from elsewhere.

Comment: i run this command**  git config --get http.proxy  ** bt nothing happen can u please explore your answer............